# JavaFX How to calculate select rows in TableView

Tags: database, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView which I would like to calculate costs from. Data in my TableView is from a database (database -> ObservableList -> TableView).

I am able to calculate total costs with the following code:

```
public static int calculateTotalCost(){
    total = 0;
    for(Items i : itemTable.getItems()){
        total += i.getCost();
    }
    return total;
}
```

However, let's say I want to filter the table so as to calculate only from specific item names... So I type in, e.g., an item name and only those appear. Then based on the remaining names I calculate the total cost of those items only... How would I best approach this?

(An option I found so far: SortedList + FilteredList...Sorry if newb question, but I am just playing around with JavaFX for the first time...)

Comment: What is wrong with the option you found?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it -- it works. It's just as I'm just starting to get familiar with JavaFX I'm wondering if there are alternatives?

Comment: If you only want to filter the calculation, you could obviously just put an `if` statement inside the `for` loop in your code. If you want only the matching items to appear in the table, then that is specifically what the `FilteredList` functionality was designed for. Clearly you could write that yourself fairly easily, but since it's already written why would you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @James_D Alright I got both things to work... however now it's throwing an error when I want to add/remove items to the database. So while I can filter, I can't edit the database

Comment: That would appear to be a completely different question to the one that is posted here.

Answer (score 0):

change you code to

```
public static int calculateTotalCost(){
    total = 0;
    for(Items i : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()){
        total += i.getCost();
    }
    return total;
}
```

above's code just calculate total costs from the selected row in TableView. make sure to set TableView to multi selection mode first by table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE), after selected some rows, run the code above to calculate the sum cost.